# SQL Find grid location for descendants in DB

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm not sure where to begin but I'd like to take a parent record that contains width and height and map a grid to it with each grid cell being of a fixed size (10mm x 10mm). The grid cells would then be numbered as so:
XXX/YYY

```
XXX = THREE DIGIT STRING REPRESENTATION OF THE POSITION X FROM 001-999
YYY = THREE DIGITS STRING REPRESENTATION OF THE POSITION Y FROM 001-999

So grid cell 1 would look like so XXX/YYY = 001001
GRID CELL 1 ON ROW 2 = 001002
GRID CELL 10 ON ROW 20 = 010020
AND SO ON...
```

I'd then like to know of the parent records descendants USING x,y location where are they located on the parent using the grid cell value defined above.

Thanks for the assistance.
Using SQL SERVER

parent:

```
id TYPE   LABEL     CREATIONCLASS   width   height
 1  1003  myParent   -225100926      454    44.44
```

descendant:

```
id  TYPE    LABEL    CREATIONCLASS   IDX      X     Y
50 4000     Eth 01   -225100949     1001     169    11
```

my results should look something like the results above with position column containing the new XXXYYY value.

I'll run the whole thing through as cte and do this for every parent and matching descendants

Output:

```
id  TYPE    LABEL    CREATIONCLASS   IDX      X     Y   newPos
50 4000     Eth 01   -225100949     1001     169    11  016002
```

Comment: What does your table look like?  What results do you want?

Comment: @gordonLinoff updated

Comment: Where does 016002 come from?

Comment: @gordonLinoff that would be new column that I'm trying to generate. the x,y value should translate into an XXX/YYY value using the parents width/height and the 10x10 grid pattern

Comment: @gordonLinoff I'm dumb I made this way more difficult than it is.  FORMAT(ceiling(x/10),'000') AS X2,FORMAT(ceiling(y/10),'000') AS Y2

Comment: . . `ceiling(x/10)` is 17, not 16.